# How to solve Unhandled Exception: The method '[]' was called on null flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scenario where a user logins in he is either redirected to dashboard or another screen. At some point data is pulled from the server and saved to the local db, and then I render it to the dashboard screen. Whenever the user logins in for the first time I get this error

> Unhandled Exception: The method '[]' was called on null

I think my dashboard is set before the data is loaded, I have tried to set the `setstate(){}`  but I keep on getting it

this is my implemntation

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }


  Future<void> init() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userid = prefs.getString("id") ?? "";
    token = prefs.getString("auth_token");
    List<ParticipantRegistrationData> list = await db.getParticipants();
    for (var i in list) {
      List<dynamic> sched = await db.getScheduleByparticipantId(i.participantid!);
      List<int> missingOrComplete = [0, 0];
      for (var j in sched) {
        if (j.showUp >= 1 ) {
          missingOrComplete[1]++;
        } else if (j.showUp == 0 && DateTime.parse(j.windowEnd).isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
          missingOrComplete[0]++;
        }
      }
      participantCounts[i.participantid!] = missingOrComplete;
    }
    setState(() async {
      participantSchedules = await db.getSchedulesByUserId(userid);
      participants = await db.getParticipantsById(userid);
      name = prefs.getString("fullname");
      getTransactions();
    });
    // use db to draw data
  }
```

then the get transaction function which gets the data to display in the dashboard

```
void getTransactions() {
    for (ParticipantRegistrationData data in participants) {
      setState(() {
        transactionList.add(WATransactionModel(
          name: data.fullname,
          participantid: data.participantid,
          gender: data.gender,
          completedScheduleid: '15',
          missedSchedule: '4',
          color: Color(0xFF26C884),
          colors: Color(0xFFFF1744),
          title: 'Name: ',
          completedSchedule: 'Schedule',
          image: 'images/walletApp/man.png',
          missed: 'Missed: ${participantCounts[data.participantid!][0]}',
          completed: 'Completed: ${participantCounts[data.participantid!][1]}',
          description: 'Number: ',
        ));
      });
    }
  }
```

the line which keep on throwing the error is

```
 missed: 'Missed: ${participantCounts[data.participantid!][0]}',
```

Which state should I set my app to load the contents first before seting the ui, Am a bit confused or how should I set the redirect(routes to refresh the page before loading the ui)
Or setting the data first before the UI?

Update 1:
I forgot to mention when I go to another screen and come back the data is already loaded and no error. The error occurs when am setting the screen for the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your problem. `void getTransactions() {` should be `Future<void>getTransactions() async {` and the when you call the function you need to await it so you have to make the function you call response in async.
So the `void getTransactions() {` should change to

`Future<void>getTransactions() async {`

and it will the data correctly with no error

Answer (score 1):

the way of writing function is correct. However, when we call a function in initState, it doesn't await itself and runs parallel to your build method. So one way is to provide a check to your build method.

For example:

```
participantCounts==null || participantCounts.isEmpty? return CircularProgressIndicator() : return Container();
```

So, in this case, your build method will show loader until your data is available.

I would also suggest you to implement any State Management technique for a better handling.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek at what point should I set this check?

Comment: In the 1st line of build method itself